# Get the element on the element when onclick on the sub element by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have these kind of list :

```
<ul id="navmenu-v">
  <li class="level1"><a id="56" class="s1">Accessories</a>
    <ul class="level2">
       <li><a id="232" class ='s2'>Apple</a></li>
       <li><a id="231" class ='s2'>Mango</a></li>
       <li><a id="154" class ='s2'>Orange</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1"><a id="63" class="s1">Componet</a>
    <ul class="level2">
       <li><a id="129" class ='s2'>Leave</a></li>
       <li><a id="658" class ='s2'>Tree</a></li>
       <li><a id="158" class ='s2'>Roof</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the id of the class s1 such as 56 and 63, when I click on the class s2?

Thanks you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do

```
$('.s2').click(function(){
   alert($(this).closest('.level1').find('a.s1').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".s2").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest(".level1").find(".s1").attr("id"));
});
```

Sidenote:

id's cannot begin with numbers according to the html spec.

Comment: Re *"id's cannot begin with numbers according to the html spec"* They [can as of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). They [can't in HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) or [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) and so it's not recommended, but...

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder : Yes thanks for your advice , just now I want to click to accept the answer too but it is not yet 10 minutes so I cannot click that.